# Fragment of SlideTabLayout: store Bitmap

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-5.0-lollipop

i am using the API21 SlidingTabLayout and SlidingTabStrips for my application.

I am saving an .tmp file of my intent camera photo. that works fine and i can see it on my phone package directory but i can store this .tmp file as .png ( i want to change the resolution because i need <1mb files instead of the 3mb files from the photo API intent)

i tried so many things in the last two hours and i can't solve it.

here is my code:

starting the intent with: takeAPicture

```
private void takeAPicture(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(getView().getContext())));

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

}
```

the path of my .tmp file: getTempFile

```
private File getTempFile(Context context){
    final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getView().getContext().getPackageName());
    if(!path.exists()){
        path.mkdir();
    }
    return new File(path, "test.tmp");
}
```

at least i handle the ActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: Joined");

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
            case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
                final File file = getTempFile(getView().getContext());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Uri: " + Uri.fromFile(file), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                try{
                    Bitmap captureBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getView().getContext().getPackageName()),"done.png"));
                    captureBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

The fact is, the .tmp file is stored and the uri for

```
Bitmap captureBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
```

is correct.

hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my code:

```
public static boolean saveImage(Context context, byte[] image, String filename) {
        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        return saveImage(context, bitmapImage, filename);
    }

    public static boolean saveImage(Context context, Bitmap image, String filename) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                imagem.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

            fos.close();
            File file = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```